# Percolation in Ultimate Frisbee (and Rugby, American Football, Basketball etc)

Tags: phase-transition, everyday-life, percolation

### Question

Has anyone ever investigated weather game dynamics in certain sports ever experiences a percolation-type transition with catching probability as the driver?

### Details

I recently started playing Ultimate Frisbee, at the beginner level, and I noticed something interesting which could also apply to other sports (Rugby, American Football, Basketball etc).  Games which involve a free field, scoring "goals" at one end of it, and, last but not least, catching something thrown by players of your team where it will go to the other team if you fail to catch it.

As a beginner, by far the most common error you make is failing to catch the frisbee.
So, every team can be labeled by "the probability a frisbee thrown by a player will be caught by another player of the same team", and the main driver for this probability is capacity to catch (Of course capacity to throw is also important here, but I think capacity to catch improves monotonically while capacity to throw quickly reaches a plateau).

Now, in our beginners games we typically let the frisbee drop MANY times between each goal, so the game stops continuously with the frisbee going to the other team.   Players run for short periods of time, accellerate and decelerate a lot, and direction changes discontinuously.  I watched a more advanced game, and lo and behold it went on much more smoothly.  An experienced friend confirmed that for experienced players many goals pass before the frisbee is dropped.   As a result, the game involves pretty much uninterrupted (but smoother) running between goals, with the probability of the team which has the ball from the start actually scoring the goal being very high (as a result a typical experienced game has a small score difference).

**Now, here is a question:**  The field is two dimensional, and you can imagine the pass of the ball as a "link" between players, which form a disordered network. 
A link which is "on" when the pass is successful and "off" if it fails.
Could it be that this dynamics approximates a percolation type transition?    Of course this is a finite system, but it would make sense that there would be a "sharp cross-over" between two regimes, a "beginner game" analogous to the non-percolating phase (where the typical number of passes is "1") and an "experienced game" analogous to the percolating phase (where the typical number of passes is >>1).

Every characteristic of the game (mean accelleration, number of stops, point difference, mean distance traveled by players) would then vary sharply between the two regimes.   The strenght of the transition would be proportional to the extent in which the capability to "keep the frisbee/ball" can be parametrized by a single number (I expect such phase transition not to exist, or to be very weak in football (Soccer for Americans :)  ), since there keeping the ball cannot be reduced to "one action".  But in Ultimate Frisbee or Rugby or Basketball it might).

I wonder if this was ever investigated before (googling indicates no).
I imagine it would be pretty easy to investigate, both empirically (game stats) and with a Montecarlo (just simulate players moving around, throwing balls at each other and accept/reject with a probability).
If a sharp transition exists, awareness of it could in principle help training, since the gameplays, strategies, and even player fitness requirements will vary quite a bit between the two phases.   My expertise in this comes from a slightly different enviroenment than sports :), https://inspirehep.net/record/893765?ln=en

Comment: Hi Giorgio,  you could, no offence intended,  improve your post 100 percent,  assuming it is a fit for here, by 1. Cutting the text in half,  be ruthless, and 2. Put your question at the end, not in the middle of a big block of text.

Comment: Naively, I agree that this is very reminiscent of a percolation transition, but in a dynamic shifting field instead of (as is usual) a static field generated with some statistical properties. I imagine such percolation problems have been studied, but I do not know much about them. I also imagine they are quite difficult.

Comment: I agree with @CountTo10 : The question is rambling. Cut the text. Get to the point. ... What exactly is the question? I don't see any. ... And is it really about physics? Seems to me it is about the human aspects of playing sports.

Comment: VTC as I find the  question very vague, and also very broad. I would be happy to retract if an effort to clarify was made. There is physics here, (in as much as I have looked up the tags, and the web) but the question will still be too broad, even after an edit,  imo.

Comment: The question is:
To your knowledge has anyone ever investigated weather game dynamics in certain sports ever experiences a percolation-type transition with catching probability as the driver?  If you know about percolation but need some context, read the long text, I am not sure how to adequately explain without it.  And I am not sure how anyone can think it is not physics related

Comment: If that is the sole question then maybe it would work better on History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange. Nice idea though.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, this is on-topic here. For example, there are many papers on flocking in Phys.Rev.Lett., and this is comparably "physical" (whatever that means).